# Not smooth playback of 4k(UHD) video

Tags: windows-10, video, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics, 4k-resolution

Please, help to configure smooth playback of 4K video on laptop [MSI PX60 6QD](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/PX60-6QD.html#hero-overview) with the following specs:

- CPU: Intel Core i7 6700HQ
- Internal graphics: Intel HD Graphics 530
- External graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M
- RAM: 16GB DDR4
- Windows 10 64-bit

I turned off built-in monitor and plugged external 4k monitor in DisplayPort.

The video file is:

```
D:\video\Astra Ultra HD Demo.ts
   General #1035
      Format : MPEG-TS
      File size : 1.38 GiB
      Duration : 12 min 14 s
      Overall bit rate mode : Variable
      Overall bit rate : 16.2 Mb/s
   Video #210
      ID : 210 (0xD2)
      Menu ID : 2 (0x2)
      Format : HEVC
      Format/Info : High Efficiency Video Coding
      Format profile : Main 10@L5.1@Main
      Codec ID : 36
      Duration : 12 min 14 s
      Width : 3 840 pixels
      Height : 2 160 pixels
      Display aspect ratio : 16:9
      Frame rate : 50.000 FPS
      Color space : YUV
      Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0
      Bit depth : 10 bits
```

I tried to use different video players (VLC, MPC, WMP, KMPlayer) - but video is played NOT smoothly, with big delays.

Windows and all drivers are updated.

===============================================
UPDATED.
Below is output from DXVA Checker for both intel and nvidia graphics:

**Intel(R) HD Graphics 530:**

```
MPEG2_A: DXVA1, SD / HD / FHD
MPEG2_C: DXVA1, SD / HD / FHD
MPEG2_VLD: DXVA2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD
MPEG2_IDCT: DXVA2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD
WMV9_IDCT: DXVA1/2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
VC1_IDCT: DXVA1/2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
VC1_VLD_2_Intel: DXVA2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
VC1_VLD_Intel: DXVA2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
VC1_VLD2010: DXVA2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD
H264_VLD_NoFGT: DXVA2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
H264_VLD_Stereo_Progressive_NoFGT: DXVA2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
H264_VLD_Stereo_NoFGT: DXVA2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
H264_VLD_Multiview_NoFGT: DXVA2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
H264_VLD_SVC_Scalable_Constrained_Baseline: DXVA2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
H264_VLD_SVC_Scalable_Constrained_High: DXVA2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
C528916C-C0AF-4645-8CB2-372B6D4ADC2A: DXVA2
8DE911C4-C898-4364-9715-1DE6B3FE773D: DXVA2
07CFAFFB-5A2E-4B99-B62A-E4CA53B6D5AA: DXVA2
MJPEG_VLD_Intel: DXVA2/D3D11
442B942A-B4D9-4940-BC45-A882E5F919F3: DXVA2/D3D11
8C56EB1E-2B47-466F-8D33-7DBCD63F3DF2: DXVA2/D3D11
HEVC_VLD_Main: DXVA2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K / 8K
75FC75F7-C589-4A07-A25B-72E03B0383B3: DXVA2/D3D11
HEVC_VLD_Main10: DXVA2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
VP9_VLD_Profile0: DXVA2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
VP9_VLD_Intel: DXVA2/D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
80A3A7BD-89D8-4497-A2B8-2126AF7E6EB8: DXVA2/D3D11
A74CCAE2-F466-45AE-86F5-AB8BE8AF8483: DXVA2
49761BEC-4B63-4349-A5FF-87FFDF088466: DXVA2/D3D11
97688186-56A8-4094-B543-FC9DAAA49F4B: D3D11
1424D4DC-7CF5-4BB1-9CD7-B63717A72A6B: D3D11
C346E8A3-CBED-4D27-87CC-A70EB4DC8C27: D3D11
FFC79924-5EAF-4666-A736-06190F281443: D3D11
F416F7BD-098A-4CF1-A11B-CE54959CA03D: D3D11
BF44DACD-217F-4370-A383-D573BC56707E: D3D11
D41289C2-ECF3-4EDE-9A04-3BBF9068A629: D3D11
2364D06A-F67F-4186-AED0-62B99E1784F1: D3D11
28566328-F041-4466-8B14-8F5831E78F8B: D3D11
50925B7B-E931-4978-A12A-586630F095F9: D3D11
```

**NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M:**

```
MPEG2and1_VLD: D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
MPEG2_VLD: D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
MPEG1_VLD: D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
VC1_VLD2010: D3D11, SD / HD / FHD
VC1_VLD: D3D11, SD / HD / FHD
32FCFE3F-DE46-4A49-861B-AC71110649D5: D3D11
H264_VLD_Stereo_Progressive_NoFGT: D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
H264_VLD_Stereo_NoFGT: D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
H264_VLD_NoFGT: D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
HEVC_VLD_Main: D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K
MPEG4pt2_VLD_Simple: D3D11, SD / HD / FHD
MPEG4pt2_VLD_AdvSimple_NoGMC: D3D11, SD / HD / FHD
9947EC6F-689B-11DC-A320-0019DBBC4184: D3D11
MJPEG_VLD_NVIDIA: D3D11, SD / HD / FHD / 4K / 8K
6AFFD11E-1D96-42B1-A215-93A31F09A53D: D3D11
914C84A3-4078-4FA9-984C-E2F262CB5C9C: D3D11
```

Comment: I would make sure that the Nvidia GPU is actually being used with a utility like GPU-Z. Thinking about it though, have you considered that the Nvidia GPU may not be powerful enough to play a 50fps 4k video file?

Comment: run [DXVA Checker](http://bluesky23.yukishigure.com/en/DXVAChecker.html) and look if your GPUs support HW acceleration for your resolution and video format

Comment: @Sonickyle27 the following is link with specs for that nvidia card https://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-950m/specifications
CPU-Z shows both nvidia and intel cards.

Comment: @magicandre1981 thank you for your reply. I've added information from DXVAChecker into question. Could you please help to determine whether the file which I'm trying to play - is compatible with my GPUs?
The file is MPEG-TS, but there is no that in the list which DXVAChecker gave me...

Comment: the video uses HEVC with 10 bits and this is supported by your Intel HD but not by your nVIDIA. in the optimus or video player settings, configure that you use the Intel HD not the nVIDIA card for decoding.